# Потребность в знаниях

Tags: php

Уважаемые пользователи ХэшКода. Я с недавнего времени начал активно изучать php и столкнулся с проблемой нехватки качественного материала для обучения. Дело в том, что таким новичкам, как я нужен доступный, понятный материал. Но в силу своего незнания, очень трудно найти качественные мануалы и книги, которые бы повели процес учение в правильном направлении. В частности, меня интересует веб-программирование. Поэтому, я обращаюсь ко всем участникам проекта за советом: подскажите, кто с чего начинал, какой способ обучения вы считаете самым обьективным? Дело в том, что в интернете много всякой литературы, много чего хорошего, чем я и сам пользуюсь при обучении, но хочется услышать, так сказать, из первых уст. Мне интересно, что подскажут практики. Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Кстати, ресурс - http://php.su - довольно-таки полезный для новичков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Антон всё правильно сказал. Я изучал PHP следующим образом:

1. Поставил Denwer
2. Написал программку типа Hello World
3. Дальше ставил перед собой небольшие
               задачки и искал их решение. Например
               сложение чисел, вывод текста, вывод
               массивов, реализация условий.
4. Потом написание регулярных
       выражений. Интересно было скачивать в автоматическом режиме информацию (афоризмы) с сайта и сохранять это на локальном компьютере. Кстати на этом этапе значимую пользу принесло то, что стал "ковыряться" в чужих, несложных скриптах.
5. Затем поставил CMS Wordpress -
           возникла необходимость в выполнении
           автоматических действий - поэтому
           пришлось изучать API и дорабатывать,
           благо это оказалось легко.
6. Ну а дальше пошла работа с Drupal, Bitrix, UMI.cms и т.п.

Comment: Тоже работаю таким же образом.  Только пока еще не убегаю сильно далеко от источников информации, набираюсь теоретического опыта. )

Comment: Всё правильно. Обычно вначале базовые знания получают, а со временем начинают появляться идеи, которые хочется реализовать - и вот на них опыт набирается быстро и эффективно.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я брал всю информацию на этих сайтах

```
http://php.su
http://php.net
```

ну и практика и еще раз практика. Помнится взял одну единственную книгу "PHP5 для профессионалов", в ней для себя нового ни чего не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Начинал с установки апача, не всё и сразу получалось, русских тогда мало было документаций, читал http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/, первым делом изучил пункт "Справочник языка", по "играл" с переменными, выполнил простенькие математические операции, по игрался с циклами и условными конструкциями, самое главное - это понять как работает функция, и использовать её в правильных целях.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется и не найдете. Предлагаю другой вариант обучения: Найдите стоящие примеры или поставьте перед собой задачу или попросите хешкод дать задание, ну и потом ищите в интернете мануалы и решения по заданию. Так будет намного эффективнее, чем просто чтение.

Comment: В некотором роде я согласен с вашим утверждением и способом обучения. Я понимаю, что такой способ очень эффективный. Но в своем вопросе я подразумевал категорию людей, которые только начали изучение. Для того, чтобы разбирать opensourse задания нужно понимать структуру кода, за который взялся. То есть нужна некоторая база - пусть не основательная (из книг ее тоже не почерпнешь - программировать надо на практике), но такая, которая позволила бы разбираться в основных вопросах.

Answer (score 0):

видео курсы "специалист", несколько упровней. Там и лабы есть и объясняют нормально. В общем, лучшее из всего, что есть. Я не сторонник видеокурсов, но там действительно говорят дело.