# Посоветуйте литературу

Tags: php, mysql, книги

Не уверен, что вопрос уместен.
Собрался писать CMS на php в связке с mysql. В основном для детального изучения пхп)
Погуглил, особых результатов не дало. Собстна сабж.

Comment: Собстно учите php и пишите... В чем проблема то?..<br>
Если хотите примеров - качаете одну их поппулярных CMS и изучаете исходники, структуру и т.д...

Answer (score 3):

Подобные вопросы:

- [Литература по созданию сложных систем на PHP + MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22967)
- [Книга для крупных проектов на PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26024)
- [Книги по изучению MySQL, XML, JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36455)

Еще вам могут быть интересны темы:

- [Книги упражнений и решений на php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29189)
- [Практика в задачах на PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28792)
- [Потребность в знаниях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20755)
- [Задачи и тесты по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39253)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно выучить PHP и не просто выучить, но и иметь опыт работы с cms, т.е. внедрение в них каких-то изменение и т.д. По php книг куча, а вот практиковаться надо будет на каком то своём проекте не большим, блог какой нибудь или, лучше, какой нибудь проект, для которого постоянно можно было что-то приделать, например САР, там скачиваешь cms любую сар (букс) без плагинов, и начинаешь сам писать то, чего у твоих конкурентов есть ,а у тебя нету, спрашивая, если что-то не знаешь у профессионалов здесь, или на другом форуме. После начать работать над проектами за деньги. Заходишь на любую биржу удалённой работы, например фриланс и смотришь, если под силу, то пишешь за сколько сделаешь. Главное, сначала, делать очень дёшево, чтобы набраться опыта, а то там очень большая конкуренция. А вот после работы на фрилансе года 1.5, можно уже создавать свою cms, кстати, сар можно разрабатывать параллельно с работой на фрилансе. Поэтому, приблизительно, чтобы суметь создать свою cms профессионально на уровне joomla нужно года 2-3.

Comment: Про 2-3 года говорите за себя :)

Comment: Это нужно выучить язык, нормально попрактиковаться, как раз 2-3 года. Я с 12 лет программирую, сейчас невозможных задач для меня нету, по карайне мере за 2 года работы ниразу не говорил "я этого не смогу сделать", всё получалось, а были разные задания, что только не придумают заказчики) А если создавать cms с минимальной практикой, то будет очень сложно и не профессионально. Куча дырок, недоработок, и главное - будет не очень интересно, т.к. часто будет надо обращаться за помощью на форум.

Comment: Не ну без опыта да, я вообще говорю что 2-3 годя это не серьезно :)<br>
Если бы оно так и было бы - никто бы их не писал... :)

Comment: Ну да, но это и не мало. А создание cms - это ещё куча опыта)